# Installing AWS key to use S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I did `aws configure` and inputted my key and secret key. i have checked that my account exists when I ran:
`aws iam list-account-aliases`
and my alias appeared.

However, when i try to upload a file to aws, I am recieving this error:

```
/Users/kchen/campaiyn-web/node_modules/skipper-s3/node_modules/knox/lib/client.js:197
  if (!options.key) throw new Error('aws "key" required');
                    ^

Error: aws "key" required
    at new Client (/Users/kchen/campaiyn-web/node_modules/skipper-s3/node_modules/knox/lib/client.js:197:27)
    at Function.exports.createClient (/Users/kchen/campaiyn-web/node_modules/skipper-s3/node_modules/knox/lib/client.js:925:10)
    at Writable.onFile (/Users/kchen/campaiyn-web/node_modules/skipper-s3/index.js:248:22)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:292:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:278:5)
    at Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:207:11)
    at Transform.ondata (_stream_readable.js:528:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Transform.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Transform.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:128:32)
    at /Users/kchen/campaiyn-web/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/build-renamer-stream.js:49:19
    at Object.opts.saveAs (/Users/kchen/campaiyn-web/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/prototype.upload.js:71:7)
    at determineBasename (/Users/kchen/campaiyn-web/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/build-renamer-stream.js:32:17)
    at Transform.__renamer__._transform (/Users/kchen/campaiyn-web/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/build-renamer-stream.js:40:7)
```

I feel that my key was not installed correctly or am i looking at this incorrectly?

Comment: You can look in `~/.aws/` to see the configuration that was created by the `aws configure` command.

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using (skipper) does not know how to pick up the credentials. 
I would recommend either passing the credential in explicitly or switching to using the nodejs AWS SDK which definitely supports this.